# Retrieving permission sets

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Does the metadata api returns the object permissions in the permissions sets? I want to retrieve the object permissions for standard as well as custom objects.

Answer (score 5):

## USING SOQL

You can fetch this information by Querying 3 objects - **PermissionSet**, **PermissionSetAssignment** and **ObjectPermissions**.

```
SELECT Id,IsOwnedByProfile,Label FROM PermissionSet
WHERE IsOwnedByProfile = TRUE
```

The above query will return the permission set that you have created and not owned by profile.Then you can use below query to get the object permissions -

```
SELECT Assignee.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.isOwnedByProfile, PermissionSet.Profile.Name, PermissionSet.Label
FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSetId
IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE SObjectType = 'XYZ__c' AND
PermissionsCreate = true)
```

Reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html

### USING METADATA

You can use metadata API to retrieve the object permissions.If you check metadata developer guide and search for **PermissionSet** , you can easily see that this type returns multiple parameters from API v29.0 onwards like-applicationVisibilities,classAccesses, fieldPermissions,ObjectPermissions, etc. 
Specifically talking about **ObjectPermissions**, the return type is `PermissionSetObjectPermissions[]` (List of PermissionSetObjectPermissions). Now this list has all the information that you require like - `allowCreate, allowDelete, allowEdit, allowRead, modifyAllRecords,object, viewAllRecords`. Out of this Object is a string type while rest are all boolean corresponding to the permissions on object.

Reference - https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf (Metadata API v.34 Summer'15 page 416)

Now if you are looking for developing this using Apex, kindly refer this package - https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi 
and this example - https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L234

Comment: I wanted to use metadata api, not SOQL to retrieve permission sets.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this
SELECT SobjectType, ParentId, PermissionsRead
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE PermissionsRead = True AND SobjectType = 'Merchandise__c'.

ObjectePermissions and FieldPermissions are child to Permissionsets. Hope this helps